# How to to get the file data out of a CMD: dir>filename.txt text file? C

Tags: c

so Im trying to create a program that reads a txt file witch is created by the dir>txtfile.txt cmd command, it would read lines with files and their data only and giving it to a struct. I dont know how to skip lines with not usable data and the size of file is separated with ˙ symbols (like: 234˙544˙123 bytes) so i dont know how to send that to the struct in one using fscanf.

Here is an example txt file:

---

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 1E41-CB5F

 Directory of C:\Users\kistejes\Desktop\test

2017. 11. 24.  22:54    <DIR>          .
2017. 11. 24.  22:54    <DIR>          ..
2017. 09. 17.  15:12           266˙466 abc.jpg
2017. 11. 24.  22:52    <DIR>          afolder
2017. 11. 24.  22:52    <DIR>          beornottobe
2017. 09. 17.  15:12           269˙197 dkfj.jpg
2017. 09. 17.  15:12           244˙070 hjkl.jpg
2017. 09. 17.  15:12           244˙399 lkjh.jpg
2017. 11. 24.  22:52    <DIR>          pink
2017. 09. 17.  15:12           249˙452 qwert.jpg
2017. 11. 24.  22:54                 0 sad.txt
2017. 11. 24.  22:52    <DIR>          someweirdfolder
2017. 09. 17.  15:12           254˙549 yxcv.jpg
               7 File(s)      1˙528˙133 bytes
               6 Dir(s)  21˙622˙124˙544 bytes free
```

---

and the laughable code i came up with (not working ofc):

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct tempfile
{
    int ev;
    int hnap;
    int nap;
    int ora;
    int perc;
    int meret;
    char nev[218];
    char kiterjesztes[4];
}tempfile;
int main()
{
    FILE *temp;
    tempfile a;
    system("dir>temp.txt");
    temp = fopen("temp.txt", "r");
    if (temp == NULL)
        return -1;
     while (feof(temp)!=1)
     {
         if (fscanf(temp, "%d. %d. %d.  %d:%d    %d %s.%s", &a.ev, &a.hnap, &a.nap, &a.ora, &a.perc, &a.meret, &a.nev, &a.kiterjesztes) == 9)
         {
             (fscanf(temp, "%d. %d. %d.  %d:%d    %d %s.%s", &a.ev, &a.hnap, &a.nap, &a.ora, &a.perc, &a.meret, &a.nev, &a.kiterjesztes) == 9);
             printf("%d. %d. %d.  %d:%d    %d %s.%s", &a.ev, &a.hnap, &a.nap, &a.ora, &a.perc, &a.meret, &a.nev, &a.kiterjesztes);
         }
         else
             fscanf(temp, "%*d. %*d. %*d.  %*d:%*d    %*d %*s.%*s\n");
     }
     fclose(temp);
    system("DEL temp.txt");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: don't parse the output of `dir`.. also use `popen` to avoid creating a temp file. Use `_readdir` and `stat` to get the information you need.

Comment: Well sorry, i forgot to mention that i am a absolute newbie to C programing, and i dont know how to implement these.

Comment: Additionally, I somehow think that it would be way easier to read it directly as a directory structure than it is to parse it.  Check out the man pages related to `dirent.h`

Comment: i did checked the features that dirent.h got, but i dont want to use any external headers.

Comment: Oh wow! This is impressive, after a few minutes of analysing the code and running it in debugging mode, i understand almost all of it, except the " [^0-9]%d %217s"  part and the magic with the size in bytes (named a.meret).

My idea is that if you skip all the stuff starting with ' ' and '\n' and lines with <DIR>  you will have the lines that needed. So if you replace the "˙" character with "" (nothing) you dont need to do the size magic.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well after a day of pain(actually i learned a lot so yay), i finaly pulled it of.

Here it is how it looks:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

typedef struct tempfile
{
    int ev;
    int hnap;
    int nap;
    int ora;
    int perc;
    int meret;
    char nev[218];
    char kiterjesztes[218];
}tempfile;

    int main(void)
    {
        char input[1024];
        char edited[1024];
        int i = 0;
        int p = 0;
        FILE *temp;
        tempfile a;

        system("dir>temp.txt");
        temp = fopen("temp.txt", "r");
        if (temp == NULL)
            return -1;

        while (fgets(input, sizeof input, temp))
        {
            if (input[0] == ' ' || input[0] == '\n')
            {
                continue;//atugorja azokat a sorokat amik space vagy ujsorral kezdodnek
            }
            if (strstr(input, "<DIR>"))
            {
                continue;//atugorja azokat a sorokat okat amikben benne van a <DIR>
            }
            while (input[i] != '\0')
            {
                if (input[i] != '˙')
                {
                    edited[p] = input[i];
                    p++;
                }
                i++;
            }
            edited[p] = '\0';                        //rongyá editelése a sornak
            p = 0;
            i = 0;
            while (edited[i] != '\0')
            {
                if (edited[i] == '.')
                    edited[i] = ' ';
                i++;
            }
            i = 0;


            sscanf(edited, "%d  %d  %d   %d:%d    %d %s %s\n", &a.ev, &a.hnap, &a.nap, &a.ora, &a.perc, &a.meret, &a.nev, &a.kiterjesztes);
            printf(edited, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %s %s\n", a.ev, a.hnap, a.nap, a.ora, a.perc, a.meret, a.nev, a.kiterjesztes);

        }

        fclose(temp);
        system("DEL temp.txt");
        printf("press enter\n");
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
```